# How can I call a context in a fragment for DrawableCompat.setTint with kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

I want to change the color of a button in fragment by control of another button in mainActivity.

The code for the fragment is :

```
lass build_8p : Fragment() {
var brush_chosen = 1
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val brush_color = arguments?.getString("brush")
    ib0.setOnClickListener {
        if (brush_chosen==1)
        {
            //val con = this.context
            DrawableCompat.setTint(ib0.drawable, ContextCompat.getColor(this.context,R.color.rndcolor1))
        }
    }
    }


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_build_8p, container, false)
}
```

The variable brush_chosen will be took from the mainActivity.

Here I want to know how to put a correct input for
DrawableCompat.setTint(ib0.drawable, ContextCompat.getColor(this.context,R.color.rndcolor1))
}

Since that line does not work.

Please tell me how and Thank you very much.

Comment: What exactly is the error? What isn't found?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use requireContext():

```
DrawableCompat.setTint(ib0.drawable, ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(),R.color.rndcolor1))
```

Answer (score 0):

To use fragment context :

```
DrawableCompat.setTint(ib0.drawable, ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(),R.color.rndcolor1))
```

To use Activity context :

```
DrawableCompat.setTint(ib0.drawable, ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(),R.color.rndcolor1))
```

both should work in your case